# Capture gesture events on MKOverlayView with an UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I try to capture events on a subclassed MKOverlayView with a UIGestureRecognizer.
However the selector never gets fired. Any ideas?

interface:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface XYOverlayView : MKCircleView {}
-(void) viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
@end
```

imp:

```
@implementation XYOverlayView

- (id)initWithOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if(self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay])
    {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = TRUE;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapRecogniser];
        [tapRecogniser release];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"XYOverlayView tapped"); 
}
@end
```

Comment: Gesture recognizers don't work on overlay views because MapKit specifically prevents them from working.  `MKMapView` puts all overlay views in container layer of class `MKOverlayContainerView`, and `-[MKOverlayContainerView pointInside:withEvent:]` always returns `NO`.  This means touches are never considered to be inside an overlay view, so touches never reach the gesture recognizers attached to overlay views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not get this to work. Switched to an custom MKAnnotationView to capture the gestures. This also has the advantage the tapable region in the window stays the same size.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in your interface and you have to import the UIKit
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XYOverlayView : MKCircleView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

Comment: OP is not using any UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods. If UIKit wasn't imported, he wouldn't make it far enough to know the method isn't firing.

Comment: Indeed, UIkit is added via the prefix header. UIGestureRecognizerDelegate is not necessary for an gesturerecognizer. However tried returning TRUE from '- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer' and  '- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch'. No luck...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify the `numberOfTapsRequired` and `numberOfTouchesRequired` otherwise the gesture recognizer doesn't know what to accept as a 'tap'.

```
tapRecogniser.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecogniser.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
```

Comment: As per the documentation these are the defaults. Specifying them does not help...

Comment: Is XYZOverlayView supposed to be a subclass of MKCircleView or MKOverlayView? If you're not going to use `initWithCircle:` why not just have it as a subclass of MKOverlayView?

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer here might be a solution: [MKOverlayView and touches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203000/111712)