# Detect touches on MKOverlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkoverlay

How can i detect touch events on MKOverlay or MKPolyline view? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472461/mkoverlayview-and-touches) and adding tapgesture on MKPolylineView but got no success.

```
    - (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
         MKPolyline *mapPoly = (MKPolyline *)overlay;

                MKPolylineView *_ucPolyView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:mapPoly];

                _ucPolyView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [_ucPolyView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
         UITapGestureRecognizer *polylineTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(polylineTapped:)];
            polylineTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [_ucPolyView addGestureRecognizer:polylineTap];

}


-(void)polylineTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    NSLog(@"Polyline is %@",tapGesture.view);
}
```

but polylineTapped method is not getting fired. All i want to acheve is to display a popup view showing details of the polyline whenever user taps on that polyline.

Comment: Did you found solution for this, since I am also facing same issue now, if you would found solution, can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and came to the conclusion that MKMapView eats all the events that would have propagated to child views such as the MKOverlayView.  I suppose that MKMapView needs to have total control of touch events in order to do pinch and zoom, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the views hitTest to examine its children even if the hit is outside the bounds.